# Efficient relationship filter in SQLite3 and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

**TLDR**: How can I speed up queries against a null relationship field?

---

**Update**: Here is the SQL being used by SQLAlchemy. Does anyone know why `LIMIT ? OFFSET ?` exists?

```
SELECT addresses.id, addresses.street, addresses.city, addresses.state, addresses.zipcode, addresses.parcel 
FROM addresses 
WHERE NOT (EXISTS (SELECT 1 
FROM results 
WHERE addresses.id = results.address_id))
 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
```

---

Some of the queries I'm doing on my SQLite3 database are moving VERY slowly. I'm surprised, because I only have about 90,000 Results instances. Here's some  object info:

```
class Address(Base):  # There are 1.45M addresses
    ...
    results = relationship("Result", back_populates="address")

class Result(Base):  # There are 90k results
    ...
    address_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('addresses.id'))
    address = relationship("Address", back_populates="results")
```

And this query is taking 25 minutes!!

```
q = session.query(Address)
addresses = [
              [row.street, row.zipcode, row.id] for row in
               q.filter(Address.results == None).limit(350).all()
            ]
```

Is this an indexing problem? Even without an index I feel like the `limit` clause should make things much faster than they are.

Comment: That query takes ~1.8s without an index given 1.45M addresses and 90k results, somewhat evenly spread among addresses. So could you provide some more details as to what leads to 25 minutes?

Comment: Perhaps you have some [hidden ORDER BY applied from somewhere](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.params.order_by)?

Comment: Let me get home and I will check on this. It’s a very simple script.

Comment: @IljaEverilä There is no ORDER BY. I have posted the raw SQL generated by SQLAlchemy. I wonder why there are ? in the query...

Comment: They are placeholders for arguments to your query, in this case your explicit limit of 350 and the implicit 0 offset.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I see. Well, I have done several different queries. I have tried `join`, `joinload`, `subqueryload` and I am beginning to wonder if my database is corrupt. I executed a `dump` to a new database - no changes. I am so confused because this query is so simple!